# Sort users by name and add them to alphabetic groups

Tags: powershell

I have the following challenge. A bunch of usernames in an array.

```
Bob.Bob@bob.com
Barbara.One@bob.com
Jane.Hase@bob.com
Zelda.Sword@bob.com
```

and want to add them with PowerShell into a set of created alphabetical groups like this:

```
GroupB contains:
Bob.Bob@bob.com
Barbara.One@bob.com

GroupJ contains:
Jane.Hase@bob.com

GroupZ contains:
Zelda.Sword@bob.com
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this can help -

```
$Array = @("Bob.Bob@bob.com", "Barbara.One@bob.com", "Jane.Hase@bob.com", "Zelda.Sword@bob.com", "bob.Bob@bob.com")
$Array | Group-Object -Property {$_.ToUpper().ToCharArray()[0]} | ForEach-Object {
"Group$($_.Name) contains:`n$($_.Group)"
}
```

Comment: great ! sorry I'm new in this, how can I deal with small letters? that they also go to the same group like "Bob" and "barbara" to group B ?

Comment: I think the code will do that for you. It groups on the basis of first character and not on the basis of upper case or lower case.

Comment: should go to the same group, thank you so much in advance....

Group**b** contains:
bob.Bob@bob.com
Group**B** contains:
Barbara.One@bob.com
GroupJ contains:
Jane.Hase@bob.com
GroupZ contains:
Zelda.Sword@bob.com

Comment: On double-checking I noticed that the grouping can be on basis of cases too.
If you have inputs like `bob.Bob@bob.com ` & `Bob.Bob@bob.com `, then it will group them separately into `Groupb` and `GroupB`. Is that what you want?

Comment: bob.Bob@bob.com & Bob.Bob@bob.com  into Group B ... that is what I'm looking for !